# How do I relearn the entire math subject

Tags: self-learning

As I am progressing through my physics undergrad, I am noticing that I am incredibly bad at math compared to my peers, and I want to learn the basics from the ground up. What is the best way of doing so, and in what order should I learn math.

Comment: Starting with a book on real analysis can't hurt. *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* is the standard undergrad introductory textbook.

Comment: An improvement would be to not inquire after "the best way" of doing something. As if to say you want to avoid failure.

Comment: What do you call the basics?

Comment: Principles of Mathematical Analysis (aka baby Rudin) is a classic but other books such as Understanding Analysis by Abbot might be easier to read. It could be tough to dive straight into baby Rudin. Personally, I’d suggest checking out some of the following books: Div, Grad, Curl and All That; the vector calculus portions of Griffiths’s book on Electromagnetism; Introduction to Linear Algebra by Strang; Hubbard and Hubbard’s book on vector calculus, linear algebra, and differential forms. Backtrack as necessary to fill in gaps in knowledge.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I personally can't think of a worse way to study and understand Mathematics than reading Rudin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from Precalc,then Calculus I ,II,III ;Differential Equations ,Linear Algebra ,Basic Probability and Statistics ,I think this will be generally enough for Physics undergrad ,if you are studying some specific math intensive  Physics courses, you might need Complex Analysis ,Real Analysis.

I was in a similar position ,Thank god we had a Lockdown(RIP those whose died),I managed to study some basics using Thomas Calculus .

Comment: Quick question, are precalc, and college algebra the same, or is precalc just algebra + trig

Comment: Precalc is all the things you need to know to learn Calculus,so that includes algebra ,trig ,functions ,graph transformation ,a bit of geometry etc